# Stateful Kafka Stream - How to restore state?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

If I am running my stream application - appA on Machine A and then I moved it to Machine B; will it remember the earlier state?

When I write simple consumer it remembers the last offset and it gets stored in __consumer_offsets itself on Broker. So no matter where I start the Consumer it will pick up from that place.

Is there such a construct for stateful stream processing applications? If I am calculating the continuous Profit and Loss of my portfolio I need to start from where it was the last run and then start aggregating new transactions to that earlier P&L number. I cannot afford to process all messages again from the start of time. I have been having a hard time in finding an article around this that explains how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't remember state unless you move the statestore as well (`state.dir` configuration).

The changelog topic will need read from the earliest offsets to rebuild the state.

There's presentations about running Kafka Steams in Kubernetes that cover some aspects of this, since Kubernetes can stop and relocate its pods... But kubernetes also has volume management features that may not be available in your scenario.

It might therefore be best to run your job on both machines to start, then you have fault tolerance, high availability with a warm standby replica / partitioned state.

Comment: Isn't changelog a compacted topic; so why changelog need to read from the beginning. As I understand stream application will store into RocksDB on local machine which would be persisted in changedlog on kafka broker. 

And Changelog is compacted topic.  

So; why would it take long for an application to restore from changelog on a different machine ?

Comment: Compacted topics can easily be hundreds of GB in size for high-frequency topics, so I don't understand your question

Comment: RocksDB is on local machine where stream application is running which gets replicated on changelog in broker.

Comment: And if I don't copy  state.dir to new machine then new app needs to be restore from changelog from broker which can be quite time consuming due to large size of chagelog in case of lot of data. Is my reasoning correct ?

And that is why you recommended warm standby replica ?

Comment: That's correct. And to restore, it needs to read from the beginning.

Comment: If changelog is a compacted topic; then why does it matter from "beginning" ? It needs to restore completely to be in a previous running state. Changelog is like in memory KTable. You insistent on "beginning" makes me think  that i am missing something.

Comment: For example, I have topic data like `userX:0,userY:1,userX:2`. I cannot just start reading at `userX:2`. It needs to start at the earliest offset, or in Consumer CLI terms `--from-beginning`.

Comment: so changelog is not actually a compacted topic; it just keeps appending RocksDB state change ? In documentation it says that chagelog is compacted topic by key so it will have only latest value in topic. So not sure what are you trying to explain. 

I was expecting only userY:1 and userx2:2 in chagelog topic in broker. I am assuming userx and userY are the key in topic.

Comment: Compacted topics are only "compacted" in the "head" of the topic. There will still exist non unique keys in the "tail" segment that has yet to be compacted.. Regardless, even if I used unique keys in my example and started consuming second userX record, and only built a table from those 3 events, it would be missing userY information, and only result in a table of one record

Comment: How long is the lag between actual adding and compaction ? I though while adding new record for that key it will overwrite value for that key as part of renention.policy = compact. And if that happens then I will not miss any latest and greatest for that topic.

Because if there is consumer subscribing to this compacted topic; I wonder how many updates will it get ?

Comment: There is no set number. Could be hours, but is checked every `log.retention.check.interval.ms`. The LogCleaner thread(s) run on some interval, and will be slower for the more partitions that exist on disk that are being cleaned or compacted. Also, the min-dirty ratio of the topic, and log-segment size are inputs to any time-calculation function between compaction events

Comment: Is it fine (or good practice) to subscribe to regular compacted topic to get latest and greatest ? e.g. to populate real-time dashboard on UI. If I do that then when the consumer will receive latest value; when producer appends to the topic or when compaction happens or both ?

Comment: For fast UI-rendering purposes, I would recommend using alternative solutions such as Kafka Connect reading from a non-compact topic, feeding a standard database. Or use Apache Pinot, Druid, Clickhouse, Couchbase, etc etc. which all offer some form of "Kafka ingestion" pipeline tools, not related to Kafka Streams. You mentioned transactions and P&L numbers, so I suggest searching for presentations and topics on how [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/company/stories/meet-the-team-datahub-engineering/) uses Kafka.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion; I will take a look at Bloomberg article.  Many thanks. 

What are good use cases for using compacted topic (other than it reduces size of log) in terms of consumption ?

If I do subscribe to that then when the consumer will receive latest value; when producer appends to the topic or when compaction happens or both the time?